# Calculating Md5 Hash of Big Files

Tags: c#, file, memory, hash, md5

I want to make it very clear and simple. What if I have 1gb ram and I'm trying to calculate md5 hash of 2gb file? Currently, I'm doing it this way:

```
private static string Md5Hash(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(input);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(32);
    foreach(byte b in hash)
    { builder.Append(b.ToString("X2")); }
    return builder.ToString();
}

// I'm using it like: 'Md5.AsString(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))'
```

So what are your suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than computing the hash of the file after you've completely loaded it into memory, use the overload that takes a `Stream`.

```
byte[] hash;
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead("Filename"))
{
    hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(input);
}
```

Comment: So, it'll not blow up the entire memory right? Real-time hash calculation with buffer streaming? That seems clear :)

Comment: @PilawyerDev That's why he uses `File.OpenRead` instead of `File.ReadAllBytes` here.