# C# MD5 Hash inconsistent on files over 2GB

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, md5, large-files

I'm writing a c# app to download Google Drive files using their V3 APIs, and checking the MD5 hash supplied by Google to confirm the download.  All is going well, and the app is working, *except* I'm getting a 75+ percent failure rate checking the MD5 hash when files are greater than 2GB in size. Some work, most don't.

If I check with a 3rd party MD5 utility, it gives the correct hash (same as Google Drive).  I've tried downloading separate to my app (ie. through the browsers), just in case my app is doing something weird with the download, but that also fails when checking the md5 hash through my app. So it's clearly something happening at my end.

I'm using the c# System.Security.MD5 library, using TransformBlock and TransformFinalBlock. I've tried different buffer sizes, just for fun, but no luck. I did also try the full file - ComputeHash(Stream) - but this fails as well).

The only thing I can see (as a complete grasping at straws) is that the inputOffset and inputCount parameters are int, which *could* account for the 2GB limit if these functions have an internal "total file size" or similar which is also an int (32 bit signed - assumed).

The other thing I am noticing is that the process will pause every 8-25%, with no CPU, disk, RAM, garbage collection, or other activity for anywhere up to a couple of minutes before it continues. When it's "running" I see disk, CPU, etc., as expected, and progress goes reasonably quickly. This pause doesn't seem to affect whether the final hash is "successful" or not, but may be related (I see it on largish files under 2GB as well).

Does anyone know if this is an issue? I've seen a couple of people asking similar questions on issues with large file hashes, but with the unhelpful answer that hashes *should* always be the same... Yes, they should, but it appears they might not be.  The weirdest thing is the occasional hash works on a large file.

Below is a simplification of the code (error checking, progress reporting, etc. taken out for quick readability - and yes, I've tried this simplified code as well - same issue).  Not the cleanest, but it works (aside from >2GB files).  Thanks in advance for any advice or knowledge of the issue.

```
            int buffersize = 65536;
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, buffersize))
                {
                    var block = new byte[buffersize];
                    int length = 0;
                    Int64 filesize = stream.Length;
                    Int64 bytesread = 0;
                    length = stream.Read(block, 0, buffersize);
                    bytesread += length;
                    while (length == block.Length)
                    {
                        md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, length, null, 0);
                        length = stream.Read(block, 0, buffersize);
                        bytesread += length;
                    }
                    md5.TransformFinalBlock(block, 0, length);
                    bytesread += length;
                }
                var hash = md5.Hash;
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
```

Comment: It seems that these are approved. [Calculating Md5 Hash of Big Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32707596/9014308), [How to compute Hash of a large file using a Hash Function (SHA or MD5)?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1fd9f0ae-98f0-4eaf-8396-c2eaa7705de1/), [Computing MD5SUM of large files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805730/9014308) Other than that, try changing the operation mode of the program to 32bit/64bit? Or why not try the MD5 hash calculation once you have downloaded the entire file?

Comment: @kunif I am checking after it's been downloaded. The others are variations on that theme. I'll try explicitly setting the build to 64bit and see.

Comment: @kunif - Thanks for the suggestions. I tried explicitly setting to 64bit and no change. :(

Comment: If that's the case, why not report an issue to both Microsoft and Google?

Comment: @kunif, I was hoping that someone would see something wrong/stupid that I'd done that would account for it. Given the thousands of developers and millions of people who would be successfully using the MD5 libraries, it seems unlikely that I alone in the world had uncovered a bug - I'm just not that good a programmer.

Comment: One risk with this code as written is the assumption that `Read` will always return a full block if you've not reached the end of the file. That is **not** [guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_): "An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - good pickup. I originally had while(length > 0), but that sometimes put me in an infinite loop, and this was working more reliably... maybe that's fixed itself as well.  Let me know if there's a better/preferred way to test for EOF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For absolutely no known reason, it now works.  As best as I can *guess* (and it's completely theoretical and shouldn't happen), I was working on other parts of the app, and this shifted the location of something to avoid whatever was wrong...

It still pauses here and there for no known reason, but hashes are now returning correctly (matching when they should, not matching when they shouldn't).

Comment: I'd still love to know any theories on what may have been wrong in the first place...